# get_page_by_title() not returning anything

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, title, plugin-gravity-forms

I'm trying to use `get_page_by_title()` to get the value of a parent custom post type through Gravity Forms.  Basically a patient name is stored in a custom post and their patient id is the post title and the new Gravity Form will populate their medications.

On advice [from the Types plugin forum](http://wp-types.com/forums/topic/gravity-forms-and-relationships/), I'm trying to establish the parent of my post type in a hidden field. The basics are working fine, I can send a value to the field like so:

```
add_filter('gform_field_value_parent_id', 'parent_id');
function parent_id() {
    return "test";
}
```

This puts "test" in the field fine, however this doesn't do anything:

```
add_filter('gform_field_value_parent_id', 'parent_id');
function parent_id() {
    $page = get_page_by_title('TESTID', 'patient');
    return $page;   
}
```

`TESTID` is the title of the post and the post type is patient, I've tried it with and without the post type but it just won't do anything.  This code is in my functions.php and I'm sure I'm missing something obvious but I just don't see it, can someone help please?

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the second parameter in `get_page_by_title`. See [get_page_by_title() reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_page_by_title). When you are testing without explicitly specified `$output` and `$post_type`, this function returns the post of type 'page' *object* by default. So you have to return `$page->post_parent` for patient's parent page ID:

```
add_filter('gform_field_value_parent_id', 'parent_id');
function parent_id() {
    // three parameters here
    $page = get_page_by_title('TESTID', 'OBJECT', 'patient');
    // return patient's parent page ID
    if( !is_null($page) )
        return $page->post_parent;
}
```

P. S. It's a good practice to enable `WP_DEBUG` in `wp-config.php` to see all errors and warnings during development stage. Often it helps to understand bottlenecks faster.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I've tried what you said and I don't know if I'm being too literal but what form do you think OBJECT should take?  I assumed it was as you'd written it here but that causes a php error (I've always had debugging turned on, it just didn't give me an error before):  Catchable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string in C:\xampp\htdocs\mydoctorschemist\wordpress\wp-includes\formatting.php on line 510  Also the Wordpress Codex show it being used without all three calls http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_page_by_title. Thanks :-)

Comment: Unfortunately I can't reproduce this error. Everything works fine for me.  Regarding `get_page_by_title`: it has one required parameter: `$page_title`. Most likely function will throw an error without it.

Comment: May be try to pass a value to your function like this: `function parent_id($value)`.

Comment: Nothing's working!  Don't you just hate it when this happens!  Any other ideas bud?  As it is debugging is giving me nothing, do you perhaps know another way of checking this we can try?  Oh one other thing when I try to use 'return $page->post_parent' or -> anything it gives me this error:  Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\mydoctorschemist\wordpress\wp-content\themes\MyTheme\functions\gforms.php on line 69

Comment: 1. I'll try to reproduce this error one more time. 2. You get this notice when there is no post with such title. I've added one more line to the code above to eliminate this notice.

Comment: Even weirder, this works perfectly: `add_filter('gform_field_value_parent_id', 'parent_id');
function parent_id() {
global $wpdb;
$posttitle = 'TESTID';
$postid = $wpdb->get_var( "SELECT ID FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_title = '" . $posttitle . "'" );
return $postid;
}`

Comment: Sorry, I'm having difficulty with the formatting of these responses

Comment: @Dave The code you just pasted is almost the part of the `get_page_by_title()` itself... The only thing I can imagine is to remove single quotes around `OBJECT` parameter. Please try it.

Comment: Hi Max, I specifically sought out the code that was basically what get_page_by_title() contained to test it, how weird is this though?  I've tried your suggestions and no matter what I try it will not work!  I've done nothing to any Wordpress Core files and as far as I know my plugin's are doing nothing weird.  The only reference to the function outside of the core definition is in the Types plugin and it is using it the same way I'm trying to just a bit more complex, no redefiniton. `$exists = get_page_by_title($_POST['wpcf']['group']['name'],
                    'OBJECT', 'wp-types-group');`

Comment: @dave, I have no more ideas. The only I could do in place of you is temporarily alter each `return` one by one in `get_page_by_title()`, `get_page()` and `get_post() functions in `/wp-includes/post.php` to see which one exactly breaks the thing and why.

Comment: Ok bud thanks for the advice.  Could you answer one more simple thing for me please?  Is there any problem with achieving this the way I found that works and just use the SQL query version?  Any precautions I need to take or will it be fine just not to elegant.  Thanks again for all your help bud :-)

Comment: @dave Hi! Sorry for late answer: I'm on vacation without a notebook. IMHO there is no problem, just one more SQL query. And, sure, it's not so elegant as builtin function.

Comment: That's cool, it's working for me so I'll just run with it!  Thanks again bud.