# get_page_by_title not working when used with a variable

Tags: pages

My page title is `This is my title`, if I try and retrieve the ID from the title like this then it does not work:

```
$mytitle = 'This is my title';
$mytitle2 = get_page_by_title( $mytitle, OBJECT, 'mycustompost' );
print_r($mytitle2);
```

But if I do this it does work:

```
$mytitle2 = get_page_by_title( 'This is my title', OBJECT, 'mycustompost' );
print_r($mytitle2);
```

What gives?  Does `get_page_by_title` not accept variables?

Comment: Tried it with a page, it works. I suggest you replace `print_r` by `var_dump` so that you'll get `NULL` result if no post is found.

Comment: I've just tried with var_dump and I am getting NULL.  So does that look like its not finding the post?

Comment: This worked for me: `$y = 'Sample Page';
$x = get_page_by_title( $y , OBJECT, 'page' );

var_dump( $x );` You should double check your code (and post type)

Comment: On testing I can see that it works fine unless the title has a dash, then it fails.  Could it be something to do with special characters?

Answer (score 4):

Man this was an annoying problem for me as well because I a function passing the variable and when tested it showed a value (**with special characters, like "&"**. If I reset the value statically it worked but otherwise same issue. I ran html_entity_decode() on the variable and it now works perfectly so thought I would pass on in case it helps someone. Here was my function:

```
public function get_id_by_code($coupon){
    $test = get_page_by_title( html_entity_decode( $coupon ), OBJECT, 'coupon' );
    return $test->ID;
}
```

Comment: I stumbled on something similar. My CPT entry had a dash in it (entered as a hyphen-minus character), but WP  displays it as an em-dash, so when I copied the rendered title into `get_page_by_title()`, it naturally didn't match what was in the database. It didn't help that my font in Sublime Text makes it very tricky to distinguish between the two as well.

Comment: This is nuts. The titles for my CPT don't even have special characters in them (alphanumeric with no spaces) yet get_page_by_title() _still_ fails without html_entity_decode(). Thanks for the fix!

Answer (score 1):

Retrieve post/page/custom-post-type id it works fine

```
$mytitle = 'This is my title';
$mytitle2 = get_page_by_title( $mytitle, OBJECT, 'mycustompost' );
print_r($mytitle2->ID);
```

**Note**:enable WP_DEBUG in wp-config.php to see all errors and warnings and use var_dump to check values in variables.

**For more info**: [read get_page_by_title() not returning anything](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/58751/get-page-by-title-not-returning-anything)