# get_page_by_title() not working if special characters are present

Tags: posts, query-posts

get_page_by_title works fine on plain text title. but when it comes to smart quotes and symbols like `#` it doesn't work. It fails to find post with the given title.

For Example:-

```
get_page_by_title('The #1 Reason to Buy Right Now – THE MONEY!!', OBJECT, 'post');
```

returns `NULL`.

But there exists a post with this title. If there is a better way to do so, then that would be great.

Comment: So this doesn't work on a vanilla install?

Answer (score 1):

You may need to html entity decode that title. Similar to the issue found [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/100445/get-page-by-title-not-working-when-used-with-a-variable/116541).  Try this:

```
get_page_by_title(
    html_entity_decode('The #1 Reason to Buy Right Now – THE MONEY!!'), 
    OBJECT, 
    'post',
));
```

Answer (score 0):

The '#' character in title is not a problem. Second parameter of the function is a string. Change `OBJECT` to `'OBJECT'`. That's all.

Comment: Good suggestion, but that shouldn't make any difference, since `OBJECT` is a core constant defined as the string  `'OBJECT'`.

Comment: True. Tested with '#' character in title and a constant and it works. Didn't test with other special characters.

Comment: It works for both 'post' and 'page'.

Answer (score 0):

Anyone stumbling on this here is the solution:

```
get_page_by_title(esc_html('The #1 Reason to Buy Right Now – THE MONEY!!'), OBJECT, 'post');
```

Escaping the value encodes the special characters to match the title.

Answer (score -1):

In case someone needs it.

```
$post = get_page_by_title(wp_unslash(sanitize_post_field( 'post_title', 'This is my Title', 0, 'db' ) ), OBJECT, 'post')
```